# Verify HTTP Authentication from PHP?

Tags: php, http-authentication

I use a lot of HTTP Authentication on 'administrative' use pages (I am the only admin) when I don't feel like building a log-in system just for myself. It works well, partly because I'm a Mac/Safari user, and Safari remembers and applies HTTP Auth passwords transparently. Pages just load normally, like you're not even using authentication.

Which leads to.... AM I using authentication?? I would hate to accidentally leave some very sensitive portions of my web server wide open.

That lead me to this idea. Can I verify `$_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']` and use that to block access? Something like this, near the top of each page:

```
if (($_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE'] !== "Basic") and ($_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE'] !== "Digest"))
{ echo "HTTP Authentication Warning!"; exit; }
```

Or I suppose a simpler `isset($_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE'])`. This seems like a safe and simple and reliable way to give a little extra protection to authenticated pages. With this, if there were ever a problem, I would find out about it very quickly.

Or I guess to ask the question more specifically:
Do you always get an AUTH_TYPE header when using HTTP Authentication?
Is there a way to cheat and force an AUTH_TYPE header even when you are not authenticated? But adding an extra header to your request perhaps?

Comment: Does this maybe help? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Not all servers will keep populating [AUTH_TYPE] once the login happens, it will still be there but it won't have a value because once the login is validated [AUTH_USER] = 'authorized user' gets populated and stays populated, and [AUTH_TYPE] becomes [AUTH_TYPE] = ''.

Comment: @digijay I'm not trying to *DO* the authentication with PHP. I'm trying to do the authentication normally (using apache config), but then from PHP, verify that I am behind that authentication before I start spewing content.

Comment: @StephanieTemple From what you say, AUTH_TYPE isn't a winner, but `isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])` should be?